# Как можно отдать Entity-объекты в json в symfony 3?

Tags: json, rest, symfony3, doctrine2

Добрый день, пытаюсь из симофни 3 отдать записи из бд в виде json, но не могу найти никакого рабочего метода чтоб сконвертировать Doctrine-объекты в json на выходе, хотя в других фреймворках такое обычно дается в виде стандартной функции. Подскажите, пожалуйста есть ли возможность сделать подобное в symfony 3?

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь данным компонентом https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html
Вот ссылка на документацию для версии 3.4 https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/serializer.html

Answer (score 1):

Я бы порекомендовал использовать `JMSSerializerBundle`. После установки bundle в контроллере вы сможете делать так:

```
$client = $em->getRepository('Client::class')->findOneBy([
    'token' => $token
]);

$serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
$result = $serializer->serialize($client, 'json');

$response = new Response($result);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

return $response;
```